# How to show Android ListView item in new layout with click

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am working on app in which i want to show some quotes and sayings in a list view and also want to Display each Quote in new layout File when user clicks on list item.This my code for Main Activity with simple listview:-

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * Created by Tauseef on 11/11/2015.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] loveArray = { 
            "Jo Pyar Hamesha Sath Rahe Wo Sacha Hai Ji,\n" +
            "Jo Musibaton Mein Kaam Aaye Wo Acha Hai Ji,\n" +
            "Kabhi Kabhi Humse Bhi Ho Jati Hai Nadaniya,\n" +
            "Kyonki Dil To Baccha Hai Ji.", "Chor to sakta hu,\n" +
            "Magar Chor nahipate use,\n" +
            "Wo shaks meri bigri huyi,\n" +
            "Aadat ki trha hai.", 

            "Ek shaam aati hai tumhari yaad lekar,\n" +
            "Ek shaam jaati hai tumhari yaad dekar,\n" +
            "Par hume intezaar hai us shaam ka,\n" +
            "Jo aaye sirf tumhe saath lekar" 
};

    private ListView loveListView;
    private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_love);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        loveListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.loveList);

        // this-The current activity context.
        // Second param is the resource Id for list layout row item
        // Third param is input array
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, loveArray);
        loveListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        loveListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {                      

                Intent newIntent = new Intent(LoveActivity.this, MainContent.class);
                newIntent.putExtra("loveArray", position);
                startActivity(newIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and here is the new activity having only textview in which i want to show the clicked list item as textView:-

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Tauseef on 11/11/2015.
 */
public class MainContent extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainContentTextView);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String data = "";
        if(intent!= null){
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if(extras != null){
                data = extras.getString("loveArray");
            }
        }
            }
}
```

Each time when i run this app and tap on list item it's show null pointer excetion and some thing else. i didn't get what kind of error actually coming in this code.

Comment: Try to create an empty array in the Receiving Class and put the content coming from Intent in it. Also I find out that naming of Class seems to be a problem....Intent newIntent = new Intent(LoveActivity.this, MainContent.class); Shouldn't is be MainActivity.this, MainContent.Class...

Comment: i already tried but not working

Comment: And if you are giving the position in the Intent. In the receiver class it will get only the index value of the Item which is clicked. You need to pass the Strings which are there in the ListView.

Comment: String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);  use this. Pass value in the intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if(extras != null){
                data = extras.getInt("loveArray");
            }
```

And use `getInt("loveArray")` instead of `getString()`

Bçoz you pass position i.e int

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(LoveActivity.this, MainContent.class);
newIntent.putExtra("loveArray", position);//Int not string
```

**Edit:** **Use below if you pass the quote message instead of position.**

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(LoveActivity.this, MainContent.class);
newIntent.putExtra("loveArray", loveArray [position]);// Pass the quote as string
```

Then

`data = extras.getString("loveArray");`will work

Comment: I followed this method but still not working, showing null pointer exception

Comment: hey now it's working but no text display in New layout. Can you help to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

Your loveArray should have more than one items. So when you start activity by clicking listview it should take array of position so change

```
newIntent.putExtra("loveArray", position);
```

to

```
newIntent.putExtra("loveArray", loveArray[position]);
```

so it takes data of perticular array of position

Answer (score 1):

The problem is from your MainActivity activity you are passing a integer(position) value and from the MainContent activity you are receiving a string value . You need to write

```
data = extras.getInt("loveArray");
```

inkstand of

```
data = extras.getString("loveArray");
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps

Instead of passing position only, just pass the String by doing

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoveActivity.this, MainContent.class);
intent.putExtra("loveArray", loveArray[position]);// this will pass the string of this position`
```

Then in MainContent Activity, do

`data= extras.getString("loveArray");`
It must work`